# Variable name from macro argument

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class SomeClass { };

GENERATE_FUNTION(SomeClass)
```

The `GENERATE_FUNCTION` macro I'd like to define a function whose name is to be determined by the macro argument. In this case, I'd like it to define a function `func_SomeClass`. How can that be done?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
#define GENERATE_FUNCTION(Argument) void func_##Argument(){ ... }
```

More information here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation

Comment: Keep in mind if you give it a macro as a parameter, there's more preprocessor magic involved to make it work.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Yes, an extra level of indirection to actually evaluate the Argument before pasting. However that does not seem to be the OP case.

Comment: What if I don't want the `func_` part?

Answer (score 10):

As everyone says, you can use token pasting to build the name in your macro, by placing `##` where needed to join tokens together.

If the preprocessor supports variadic macros, you can include the return type and parameter list too:

```
#define GENERATE_FUNCTION(RET,NAM,...) RET func_##NAM(__VA_ARGS__)
```

..so, for example:

```
GENERATE_FUNCTION(int,SomeClass,int val)
```

..would expand to:

```
int func_SomeClass(int val)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#define GENERATE_FUNCTION(class_name) func_##class_name##
```

Comment: What does the final ## do?

Comment: Apparently makes it not work at all :) (GCC via mingw64)